# How can I programmatically get the actual scoring values from the FHIR Questionnaire for the GCS example?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am *just getting started* with HL7 FHIR and I am having a hard time digging into it the specifics of how the Questionnaire (and QuestionnaireResponse) resource is supposed to be used. We would like to create a questionnaire that has some kind of scoring system. We have previously implemented the Glascow Coma Scale (GCS) ourselves in our own proprietary (minimal) model, so when I found GCS being listed on the [examples page](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/questionnaire-examples.html) I thought it would be a good start for understanding this.

The first question I ask myself is, where are the actual scoring values? The Questionnaire resource lists stuff such as http://loinc.org/ValueSet/LL357-5 as the ValueSet, which contains stuff such as this:

```
 "compose": {
    "include": [ {
      "system": "http://loinc.org",
      "concept": [ {
        "code": "LA6562-8",
        "display": "No motor response"
      }, {
        "code": "LA6563-6",
        "display": "Extension to pain"
      }, {
        "code": "LA6564-4",
        "display": "Flexion to pain"
      }, {
        "code": "LA6565-1",
        "display": "Withdrawal from pain"
      }, {
        "code": "LA6566-9",
        "display": "Localizing pain"
      }, {
        "code": "LA6567-7",
        "display": "Obeys commands"
      } ]
    } ]
  }
```

Each of those codes should map to some numeric value and no matter which resource I check out, I cannot find any such values. So confusing. The [html page for LL357-5](https://loinc.org/LL357-5/) even lists the values, so they must be found *somewhere*.

The second thing is that I thought the Questionnaire resource could somehow instruct/point to *how* the score could be calculated, and I don't really find any such hints. *I* know the algorithm, but is it not so that a system should be able to receive this Questionnaire, render it, accept values and produce a QuestionnaireResponse containing a score from some kind of referenced algorithm? How does the FHIR Resources say how one actually computes this score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convey the values, use the http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/ordinalValue extension.  It can appear both CodeSystem and ValueSet concepts and also on Questionnaire options.

Handling embedding calculations is more sophisticated than the base Questionnaire resource is set up for.  (FHIR resources, in general, only try to represent functionality that most systems that support Questionnaires know how to do, and the lowest common denominator for Questionnaires in healthcare is relatively low.)  However, there's an implementation guide called [Structured Data Capture (SDC)](http://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/sdc/) that describes a bunch of advanced behavior.  Doing calculations is covered in the [advanced behavior](http://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/sdc/behavior.html) section.  There's an example that shows how everything fits together [here](http://build.fhir.org/ig/HL7/sdc/Questionnaire-questionnaire-sdc-profile-example-PHQ9.xml.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's a great start for us, as we need to do lots of computations later on. With regards to the first question, I was unsure if the GCS example _has_ this at all? Or do they basically leave mapping a label to an ordinal in the (external) implementation for the score?

Comment: Are you asking whether the LOINC-defined ordinal values are brought across into the FHIR representation?

Comment: Yes. I'm basically wondering if a "FHIR aware" system should be able to render the example form with ordinals and compute a GCS score, given just the Questionnaire and QuestionnaireResponse resources. As is apparent from my question I am really not aware of the possibilities or restrictions that FIHR allows for 

Comment: Could, yes.  Guaranteed to - no.  There's no mandate to support *any* optional elements in the core spec, let alone extensions.  Also, even if a system supports ordinal values, that doesn't mean it will display them.  (Typically, ordinals live behind the scenes.)

Comment: Thank you. Still, I am really not closer to finding the answer to my original question: are the ordinals present anywhere? Say, the system is aware of LOINC and GCS and whatnot. Can it retrieve the ordinals from somewhere based on the information provided? Say they changed the weighting or something. It would be good to be able to retrieve the updated numerical value for LA6562-8.

Comment: My recommendation would be to ask that on the [terminology](https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/179202-terminology) stream on http://chat.fhir.org.  (My short answer is 'probably not yet, but the right people can be dragged into that conversation and possibly make it happen'.)

Comment: OK, thank you, Lloyd. I was just under the impression that the GCS example was pretty much "ready to render", but now I understand that it would usually require quite a bit of machinery around it to make sense of it. I think this exemplifies that the world of FHIR is missing some end-to-end example implementations to make getting started a bit smoother for developers. There is so much good technical documentation at hl7.org, yet surprisingly little that ties all the together into running (toy) systems to make sense of all this abstractness :)

Comment: The core spec is too generic to provide much practical implementation guidance.  I see it as defining the building blocks from which real systems can be produced.  The detailed guidance comes in the form of implementation guides - the better funded of which also include reference implementations.  For example, the SDC has a number of implementations, some of which are open-source.

Comment: Great tip. Found the WIP update for FHIR r4 to be very usable. http://hl7.org/fhir/uv/sdc/2019May/